# Trying to translate a carriage return into a <br /> html tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an XML feed that im pulling via javascript and translating it into something more HTML friendly, but im caught up on how to translate carriage returns into an html br tag

I tried something like this

```
text = text.replace('\r','<br />');
```

to no avail..

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `\n` rather than `\r`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Javascript's replace function only replaces the first occurence if you use a string as the matching criteria. To replace all you can use regex.

Try something like this

```
text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"<br />");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 25):

You could just apply CSS `white-space:pre` on the element, exactly like the HTML `<textarea>` element is internally doing:

```
<span style="white-space:pre">your  text  \n will \n be \n on multiple \n lines</span>
```

*(note: a class is more recommended than style, the above is just a kickoff example)*

Comment: Excellent suggestion - I used "white-space:pre-line" to get the desired effect (Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: `white-space: pre-line` is the ticket if you just want to preserve the lines and not other white space.

Comment: Don't know what that magic style actually means, but it certainly does the trick !

Comment: This solution is way more effective than string manipulation, especially if the text you're displaying was originally captured from a <textarea> input box. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There could be newline characters instead of carriage returns. I would use this:

```
text = text.replace(/\r\n?|\n/g, '<br />');
```

Which will replace all instances of `\r\n`, `\r`, and `\n` with a `<br />`, but won't replace `\r\n` with two breaks, which is desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = text.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the feed manually. It probably uses another end of line (EOL) type than `\r`.

Also to replace all occurrences of the EOL type, you need to use a regex in the [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function. Once you have found the correct EOL type, use it like this:

```
text = text.replace(/<type here>/g, '<br />');
```

(of course you need to replace `<type here>` with your found EOL type.