# carriage return encoding

Tags: javascript, html, encode

through queries to a Database I am retrieving such data that I previously inserted through **HTML** `textarea` or `input`. When I get the response from my DB , in a `JSON` object the `text` field looks like this :

```
  obj :  {
           text :  [some_text] ↵ [some_text]
         }
```

I tried to replace with this `function` :

```
 string_convert = function(string){
  return string.replace("&#8629",'<br>')
               .replace('&crarr','<br>')
               .replace('/[\n\r]/g','<br>');
 }
```

I have to show this string in **HTML** ,but it does not seems to work. I'm using `UTF-8`

Any advice?

Comment: What is "↵"? Please show the real JSON.

Comment: Have you tried `string.replace('↵', '<br>')`?

Comment: ↵ is the char that it actually shows up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you have enclosed your regex in quotes. This is incorrect.

```
.replace('/[\n\r]/g','<br>');
         ^         ^
       remove these two quotes
```

The quotes are unnecessary because the regex is already delimited by the slashes.

By putting quotes in there, you've actually told it that you want to replace a fixed string rather than a regular expression. The fixed string may look like an expression, but with the quotes, it will just be seen as a plain string.

Remove the quotes and it will be seen as an expression, and it will work just fine.

One other thing, though -- in order to make your regex work perfectly, I'd also suggest modifying it slightly. As it stands, it will just replace all the `\n` and `\r` characters with `<br>`. But in some cases, they may come together as a `\r\n` pair. This should be a single line break, but your expression will replace it with two `<br>`s.

You could use an expression like this instead:

```
/\r\n|\n|\r/g
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the ending semicolons `;` in your code:

```
string_convert = function(aString){
  return aString.replace("&#8629;",'<br>').replace('&crarr;','<br>');
}
```

this does not necessary solve your problem, but it could likely.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Trying to translate a carriage return into a 
 html tag in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6975822/139917)

```
text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"<br />");
```