# Is there any way to change value of textarea with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make markdown editor with auto resizable textarea.

I'm using [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) library. But when I change value with `value={marked(this.props.text)}`, it outputs like: `<p>Hello</p>`

I can't even use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or `innerHTML` property since textarea doesn't render HTML.

When I use elements such as p, It doesn't look like textarea.

***Can someone give me a hint?***

Comment: [DraftJS](https://draftjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: if you get your markdown editor done, can you email me please? I've been looking into how to do this for a while now with no success.

Comment: Yes, sure. Leave your email here, I'll send you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975787/trying-to-translate-a-carriage-return-into-a-br-html-tag-in-javascript)

In other to make the element look like `textarea`, you should translate a carriage return into a `br` html tag.

`In this post:`

> You could just apply CSS `white-space:pre` on the element, exactly like the HTML `textarea` element is internally doing:

```
<span style="white-space:pre">your  text  \n will \n be \n on multiple \n lines</span>
```

[Also read this comment - about carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35375158/8763264)